# Google Map not loading after page submit

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know there are lot of question regarding the same title, but unfortunately I didn't find a working solution yet, thus I'm posting another.

I'm trying to load simplest google map view and it is not loading at all when page loading or after form submission. however when I refresh the page it is always loading properly.

code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div class="map-container">
    <div id="map" ></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .map-container{width: 100%;height: 400px;}
    #map{overflow: hidden;position: relative;width: 100%;height: 100%;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        minZoom:1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(15, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    /* I have already tried this code as well without success 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    */
</script>
```

when I checked the console I didn't see any errors, however there is a warning for #no-api-keys, as I'm in developing stage I does not care that much.

after submission or page loading:
[image: after submission or page loading]

after page refreshing:
[image: after page refreshing]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We would need to see the full page, but if your script is laid out like the snippet it stands a good chance of failing. The css should be in the head, the html in the body and the javascript just before the closing body tag. Just checkin'

Comment: that make sense, yes I didn't place the code properly. I will try that

Comment: it helps to reduce the error, but not fix 100%. because still sometimes it is not loading the map. I must say that it reduce the error rate

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The posted code works as is for me ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f33unv1h/1/), [direct copy paste](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f33unv1h/3/))

Answer (score 1):

```
<scrip src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;
    key=APKEY&sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you change

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

to

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

and add your scripts in your header between `<head>` `</head>`. I believe it can solve your problem.

Comment: Can you copy paste the error showed on the browser console before refreshing ?

Comment: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keysutil.js (line 220)
Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Comment: You have to activate your Maps API from the Google Developers Console and give access to your URL to use the API or generate an API key that you have to include in your javascript.

Here is how to do it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=fr#key

Answer (score 0):

when you load the page the script calls. after that hide and show of script it would not execute. 
Change script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadMap(){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            minZoom:1,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(15, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });
    }
    /* I have already tried this code as well without success 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    */
</script>
```

call the loadMap() function after form submission.